# Pass a dictionary with error message and print the error message

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate a form from backend itself. I've made a `dictionary` of error message:

```
error_messages = {
            'error': form.errors,
        }
```

and passed it to **HttpResponse**:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_messages))
```

i want to show the error message when the form is invalid.

This is my `updaterow` view:

```
def updaterow(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        error_messages = {
            'error': form.errors,
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_messages))
        else:
            form = EntryForm()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'), id)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

I have to make changes in `else` part also so kindly help me with that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have your code the wrong way around. If the form is valid there are no error messages.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'), id)
    else:
        form = EntryForm()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_messages))
```

Note that if you are making an ajax request, then your JavaScript will have to check the status code for the redirect response and take the appropriate action.

Comment: I am making an ajax request to update my entry. your code is working fine but the output that i was expecting is not the same. Your code is showing this output "{"error": {"roll": ["This field is required."]}}" on a blank page.